# Elasticsearch no longer returns correct document count unless I use _count API to search again

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch 7.10.2 server with 2.8M documents

```
# curl IP:9200/_count
{"count":2819000,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":2,"skipped":0,"failed":0}}
```

The search request shows only 10K rows are present,

```
# curl IP:9200/bigdata/_search?pretty -d @/root/query -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.98024774,
    "hits" : [ ... ],
  }
}
```

But there's actually 1.4M matches

```
# curl IP:9200/bigdata/_count?pretty -d @/root/query -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
{
  "count" : 1442357,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}
```

My problem is I had to make two API calls to get the filtered row count, how can I get both with a single API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ES 7.0.0, the `hits.count` value is not an integer value anymore but an [object that indicates the approximate hits count](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/33028) in case there are more than 10000 results (i.e. the default value of `track_total_hits`). You can change this value if you want to increase the count up to which accurate results count are counted or if you want to keep the old semantics, you can simply send your query with `rest_total_hits_as_int=true`.

```
curl IP:9200/bigdata/_search?pretty&rest_total_hits_as_int=true -d ...
```